# Mandrill invalid key error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cloud9-ide, mandrill

I have a problem with an app developing on cloud9. I'm using mandrill to send email but it gives me a problem with configuration. It seems to be an invalid key error but in local development it works with the same configuration...

There are my smtp in development environment:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: config.app_domain }
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: 'smtp.mandrillapp.com', 
    port: '587',
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: ENV['mandrill_username'],
    password:  ENV['mandrill_password'],
    authentication: :plain,
    domain:    ENV['mandrill_domain']
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: If you open a console on cloud9: `rails console` & enter `ENV['mandrill_username']` do you receive the correct username back?

Comment: @Rob yes it's correct. i'm using figaro gem for environment variables. the problem isn't the variables.

Comment: There's likely something else happening here, but the 'invalid-key' error is masking the underlying issue. If you add config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true and restart your app and try sending again, you should be able to see what's happening behind the scenes to troubleshoot further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Cloud9 workspaces are hosted on GCE servers, there are restrictions in place for sending email from a GCE instance. The following article explains the restrictions:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/